# How to set in one date range using sql?

Tags: sql

my dates

```
Dates
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
2011-03-07 00:00:00.000
2011-03-08 00:00:00.000
2011-03-13 00:00:00.000
2011-03-14 00:00:00.000
2011-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

How to convert this dates in to one date range like below

i need output like this'

```
Date_from                 Date_to
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000   2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2011-03-03 00:00:00.000   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
2011-03-07 00:00:00.000   2011-03-08 00:00:00.000 
2011-03-13 00:00:00.000   2011-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first range be the 1st - 3rd, not 1st - 1st and 3rd - 3rd?

Comment: Further, how do you define which dates count as the first/last of the range? For example, why isn't the 3rd - 7th a range? Why is the final range 13-15 and not 13-14, 14-15?

Comment: STATE YOUR RDBMS PLEASE! (as I requested on your previous question...)

Comment: in my database dates are mansion like first table. In this some dates are missing. so i need to arrange that table like second. which the date ranges are existing

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer any of the questions in the preceding comments, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005+

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Dt) - 
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY,0,Dt)  ) AS Grp
         FROM   Dates)
SELECT MIN(Dt) AS Date_from,
       MAX(Dt) AS Date_to
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY Grp
```